# outline breaks border-radius

Tags: css, google-chrome

I tried to look around on google for the answer but unfortunately did not have any luck. For some reason the following CSS does not display a border radius:

```
      .mainContent
      {
          margin-right: auto;
          margin-left: auto;

          background: white;
          outline-color: black;
          outline-width: thin;
          outline-style: solid;
          border-radius: 5px;
          height: 100px;
          width: 500px;
     }
```

if I remove the the outline chunk it works just fine. With the outline, I just have the DIV with an outline but without rounded corners. I am testing this in Chrome (webkit). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Outlines aren't expected to follow any curvature in the borders.

Comment: So in other words, I have use the border property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border-radius` works for `border`, not outline!

This means you'll need to use borders. Outlines are not really for decorative use, more for `:focus` states and things like that.

If it bothers you that the width will increase when you add a border, use:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

to make things make a bit more sense. There is a polyfill for oldIE to make it work there too.

(Read http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ for more info)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
.mainContent
{
     margin: 0 auto;
     background: white;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     border-radius: 5px;
     height: 100px;
     width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I tend to stay away from borders since they cause issues with floating divs.

Comment: But yes, this solves the issue. I was just wondering if there way some way to get outline to work with borders :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be `outline-radius` but there is no such property (yet) in CSS.

If you need two borders of different colors that curves, you can nest elements or do some CSS trickery using the `:before` pseudo-element:

```
div {
    border: 4px solid #000; 
    border-radius: 12px; 
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
div:before {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    border: 4px solid #aaa;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Voila!

[image]
    ​

http://jsfiddle.net/35Tjn/